# WebServices, what to unit test?

Tags: spring, web-services, hibernate, unit-testing, junit

I am developing a web application using Spring + Hibernate, plus CXF to convert my Service layer into a WebServices endpoint. I want to unit test my code, and when it comes to the DAOs I have no trouble: I create an in-memory database filled with my test data, then test DAOs against that.

But when testing the Service layer, most of my methods are like these:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveProgramacion(ProgramacionDTO programacion) {
    programacionDAO.persist(this.map(programacion, Programacion.class));
}
```

That is, my method just maps the VO to a DTO (using an external mapper) then calls a method of my DAO. Just that.

I used mockito to mock my DAO but honestly there are no instructions to provide mockito with since the service method itself does very little and does not check the DAO result. Given the fact that the mapper is an external dependency and thus would require its own unit test, what should I be testing here? What would be a proper unit test in this case?

Comment: What is the definition of `map`? Is this something you can replace with a call to a mock so that you can ensure it was called correctly? If so, you can then write a test that verifies `persist` was called using the result obtained from calling `map`.

Comment: map calls an external dependency bean based on Dozer mapper so yes, I guess I should create a mock for that too